# Centralizer action on components of Springer fibers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, springer-fibres

Let $G$ be a complex adjoint group. Let $u\in G$ be unipotent. The group $A(u):=\pi_0(Z_G(u))$ acts on the set of components of the Springer fiber $\mathcal{B}_u$, the variety of Borel subgroups that contain $u$. We know $\mathcal{B}_u$ is equi-dimensional.

> Could it be true that every element of $A(u)$ stabilizes at least one component of $\mathcal{B}_u$?

My motivation is the following: When $G$ is the corresponding split group over $\mathbb{F}_q$, I wish to say "$\#\mathcal{B}_u(\mathbb{F}_q)$ has the order of $q^{\dim\mathcal{B}_u}$." But then we need the above property to make sure the Frobenius stabilizes at least one component. Thank you!

Comment: $A(u)$ doesn't act on the set of components. It acts on the vector space freely generated by them, and not as a permutation representation. I suppose your question still has sense, though, i.e. whether for each $g\in A(u)$ does there exist a component $C$ s.t. $g\cdot \vec C = \vec C$.

Comment: The action of $Z_G(u)^o$ on the set of component has to be trivial, giving the $A(u)$-action on the components. Nope? Or maybe my language was too bad...

Comment: Argh, I confused this with the $W$-action, of course you're right.

Comment: In fact, I was confused for more than an hour before I realized I don't need the Springer action at all to ask this question. I did however rely on Pramod's Lusztig-Shoji algorithm package to check that this is true up to B4, C4 and G2 ...

Comment: In your remark about motivation, it isn't clear to me what you mean by "has the order of".   What does this mean when $u=1$, so $\mathcal{B}_u =\mathcal{B}$ (the full flag variety)?   In type $A$ the flag variety is just projective space of the appropriate dimension and thus has for instance $q+1$ points over $\mathbb{F}_q$ if rank $G = 1$..

Comment: Ouch - pardon for the language again. By "has the order of $q^d$" I meant to say things like there exist universal $C_1,C_2>0$ such that $C_1q^d<\#\mathcal{B}_u(\mathbb{F}_q)<C_2q^d$.

Comment: I think your basic question has the answer yes, and in fact the entire group $A(u)$ should act trivially on at least one irredudible component of the Springer fiber.    Have you looked at the work of Spaltenstein in Lect. Notes. in Math. 946 (1982)?    This comes from his thesis work at Warwick supervised by Lusztig.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will go check Spaltenstein's book. I should also have said that my $\mathrm{char}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is large, so that this growth rate result is really equivalent to the original question.

Comment: Note that Spaltenstein works in greater generality (with a reductive group that might not be connected), but his tables in Chapter IV may be useful.   For exceptional types, some useful data is given in tables in Carter's 1985 book (based heavily on Spaltenstein's work), but note that several bonds were omitted in Carter's version of the partial ordering diagrams for nilpotent orbits.    In both sources, good prime characteristic is allowed.